metabase cant load the dashboards
my metabase has problem loading my dashboards and tables. it take so much time on loading the data and finnally it says :
Still Waiting…
This usually takes an average of 0 seconds.
(This is a bit long for a dashboard)
my dashboards were ok for a month but today this happened for me.
my connection to database is ok and there is no problem with my sql queries so the problem is just from the metabase it self

this tool is using IPv4 for communicating to data base.
So when your Ip changes you must change your Ip in the configuration of the meta-base, then there is no problem connecting to the data base.
use ifconfig or ipconfig or ip addr to check if your Ip is changed
